# virt-install in python script

Tags: python, shell, virtual-machine, libvirt

I have been tasked to create virtual device using virt-install by writing it as a shell script.  How can I achieve the same in python script? I'm new to both virt-install and python. Thanks!

```
virt-install \
   --name centos7 \
   --ram 1024 \
   --disk path=./centos7.qcow2,size=8 \ 
   --vcpus 1 \
   --os-type linux \
   --os-variant centos7 \
   --network bridge=virbr0 \
   --graphics none \
   --console pty,target_type=serial \
   --location 'http://mirror.i3d.net/pub/centos/7/os/x86_64/' \ 
   --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'
```

(virtinstall.sh) and runs fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use subprocess.
Here's a sample:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call('date')
Wed Jan  4 17:36:58 IST 2017
0
>>>
```

libvirt has a python interface. So, if you are planning to use Python - you can directly use the python interface.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-python-kvm-scripting1/

Answer (score 0):

Use python `os.system()` 
`os.system('virt-install --name centos7 --ram 1024 --disk path=./centos7.qcow2,size=8 --vcpus 1 --os-type linux --os-variant centos7 --network bridge=virbr0 --graphics none --console pty,target_type=serial --location 'http://mirror.i3d.net/pub/centos/7/os/x86_64/' --extra-args 'console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial'')`

Or use `subprocess`

Ex:
`from subprocess import call`
`call('ls')`